# Istio externalName + egress gateway tls origination host is not replaced

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, istio, istio-gateway

I am trying to configure egress gateway with tls origination using service type ExternalName.
I followed this example: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-tls-origination/

But I am having Host problems with the request because of the SNI, I have to change the host because of the SSL from example-test to example.com, I tried to set header host and rewrite authority on virtual service but didn't work, and now I am trying to use envoy filter but I got nothing so far:

```bash
curl example-test
```

cause a 502 and 400 on the istio-proxy:

```bash
GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 UPE upstream_reset_before_response_started{protocol_error} - "-" 0 87 6 - "-" "curl/7.75.0"  "example.com" outbound|80|example-test|egressgateway-internal.istio-system.svc.cluster.local service_entry_match
```

Gateway:

```bash
 HTTP/1.1" 400 DPE http1.codec_error - "-" 0 11 0 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" - -  example.com -
```

Destination rule configuration:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: egressgateway-for-example
spec:
  host: egressgateway-internal.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: example-test
    trafficPolicy:
      loadBalancer:
        simple: ROUND_ROBIN
      portLevelSettings:
      - port:
          number: 80
        tls:
          mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
          sni: 'example.com'
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: originate-tls-for-example
spec:
  host: 'example.com'
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      simple: ROUND_ROBIN
    portLevelSettings:
    - port:
        number: 443
      tls:
        mode: 
        sni: 'example.com'
```

Service Entry  and service type externalName configuration:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: example-test
spec:
  hosts:
  - 'example.com'
  ports:
  - number: 80
    name: http-port
    protocol: HTTP
  - number: 443
    name: https-port
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: example-test
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: example.com
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    name: tcp
```

Virtual service ( I tried the rewrite on destination to authority and set Host to example.com and did not work)

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: direct-example-through-egress-gateway
spec:
  hosts:
  - 'example.com'
  gateways:
  - egressgateway-internal
  - mesh
  http:
  - name: "service_entry_match"
    match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
    route:
    - destination:
        host: egressgateway-internal.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        subset: example-test
        port:
          number: 80
      weight: 100
  - name: "tls_destination"
    match:
    - gateways:
      - egressgateway-internal
      port: 80
    route:
    - destination:
        host: 'example.com'
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
```

And the gateway:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: egressgateway-internal
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: egressgateway-internal
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: https-port-for-tls-origination
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
    - 'example.com'
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
```

Envoy filter:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: test-add-example-host
  namespace: default
spec:
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: SIDECAR_OUTBOUND
      listener:
        portNumber: 80
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
            subFilter:
              name: "envoy.filters.http.router"
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value:
       name: envoy.lua
       typed_config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua"
          inlineCode: |
            function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
              if (request_handle:headers():get("Host") == "example-test")
              then
                request_handle:logInfo("[INFO] Add Host to request...")
                request_handle:headers():replace(":authority",'example.com')
              else
                request_handle:logInfo("[INFO]debug..")
              end
            end
```

Comment: The issue was on virtual service, the external name was created on default namespace and it is necessary add the FQN to hosts ```- example-test.default.svc.cluster.local```

Comment: Did you get this to work in the end?

Comment: yes I did, I just fixed the virtual service namespace or use the virtual service but with the right FQN